# How can I inspect x86/x64 code generated by V8 from WebAssembly?

Tags: v8, webassembly, embedded-v8

https://webassembly.studio/ allows inspection of WebAssembly (WASM) files and the corresponding SpiderMonkey-generated x86 code. *I'd like to similarly inspect instructions generated by V8's WASM compilers (Liftoff and TurboFan)*.

I'm entirely unfamiliar with V8's codebase/API (I compiled & linked it and followed some tutorials, though). There seems to be a `v8::CompiledWasmModule` class available, but it does not seem to expose access to generated x86/x64 instructions by either Liftoff or TurboFan.

[WebAssembly - adding a new opcode](https://v8.dev/docs/webassembly-opcode) describes the process of adding a WASM opcode to V8. Seemingly appropriate functions for WASM compilation/execution are available in the mentioned classes. Though, these seem rather deeply layered within the V8 codebase and would be difficult to access were I to link V8 as a library. Also, I'm unsure if this corresponds to Liftoff or TurboFan.

Could anybody familiar with the V8 codebase give me some pointers as to how I can access Liftoff and/or TurboFan's WebAssembly compilation module, as to obtain x86/x64 code?

Answer (score 1):

To inspect generated code, you can run the `d8` shell with the `--print-wasm-code` flag. You'll need either a debug build, or a release build with the `v8_enable_disassembler = true` GN arg.

There's no existing way to retrieve generated code via V8's API; so if that's what you want, then you'd have to add it. Keep in mind that V8 is not designed to be a standalone compiler, which means generated code assumes that it's going to run "inside V8", so if you wanted to use it for anything else, you'd have to make significant modifications.